# Get file names from specific path in android

Tags: android

How can I reach to a specific folder in computer (local or a server) and get all names of the things in it and list it in android?

Comment: Which protocol are you using? FTP?

Comment: Assume that the folder that I am trying to reach is on my computer (where I am developing android project). Im trying to reach a specific path and get all the names of the folders images and any other things in it.

Comment: You have to give us more details on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to understand that some "program" should be install on computer, e.g. **[FTP server](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server)**. Then you can implement ftp protocol or better just use one of libraries that already do it for you. I suggest you to use [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/).

Because question is very not specific, I can't give you direct code snippets, only direction.

Comment: I am just said how you can do this in easiest way.